# how to submit a form using link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to click on below link instead of the traditional way:

E.g

```
 <a href="">Click Here</a>
```

instead of :

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Here"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$('a').click(function() { $('form').submit(); });`

Comment: Where are you stuck? Post your attempt, if any...

Comment: Why? Links are not designed to submit forms, submit buttons are. Use CSS if the appearance of a button is undesirable for you.

Comment: You can style button to look like anchor if that's what you wish.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan Who is being cruel in here? I don't see any offending comment except yours?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Sure. I'm the one who giving his "why" questions to him instead of giving an answer.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan — Trying to understand the problem and giving a good solution instead of spoon feeding code to do exactly what was asked for, even if that is harmful, is not being cruel.

Comment: Use onclick attribute

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
onclick="document.forms[0].submit()"
```

This will submit the first form in the document.

Or, if the form has `name` property, you can use

```
onclick="document.form_name.submit()"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('yourForm').submit();">Click Here</a>
```

And your form should have an `id`:

```
<form id="yourForm" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, if you have to use an a tag for submitting.

I suggest you to use jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form > a.submitter').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But i strongly suggest you to use a button tag for submitting forms. Because buttons are easy to style.

just use:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
<a href="#" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;" onclick="this.form.submit();">Submit</a>
```

Are you using image, or something like that in the `<a>` element?